# CanCan::AccessDenied in LocationController#show for all roles

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, devise, roles, cancan

Using CanCan for authorization and Devise for authentication. I have three roles. Admin role has access to all actions. But when I am logged in as an admin, I still get Access Denied. What am I doing wrong?? Also I have been following [this wiki for implementation](https://github.com/ryanb/cancan/wiki/Role-Based-Authorization)

This is my controller code

```
class LocationController < ApplicationController
  #before_filter :authenticate, :only => [:title_clearing]
  before_filter :authenticate_user!
  load_and_authorize_resource

  def show
    @data = []
    if params[:Date].match(/^(19|20)\d\d[- \/.](0[1-9]|1[012])[- \/.](0[1-9]|[12][0-9]|3[01])$/).nil? == true
      @message = "Wrong Date Format"
    else
      @data = Location.show(params[:Date])
      if @data.size == 0
        @message = "No data exists for "+ params[:Date]
      else
        @message = "Data loaded successfully for "+ params[:Date]
      end
    end

    if params[:Date] == "all"
      @message = "All records loaded"
      @data = Location.show("all")
    end

  end
end
```

In the ability.rb

```
if user.is? :admin
    can :all, :location 
end
if user.is? :titleclearing
    can :title_clearing, :location
end
if user.is? :acquisitions
    cannot :title_clearing, :location 
end
```

In the user model

```
def role?(role)
    roles.include? role.to_s
end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

User proper CanCan convention:

```
if user.is? :admin
  can :manage, Location
end
```

Or, you can manage all:

```
can :manage, :all
```

Comment: Thanks, that worked; in a way. Whereas it was previously showing AccessDenied for all users belonging to all roles, now everyone's being let through! As you can see from the code I want role=titleclearing to only access title_clearing action and role=acquisitions to acess all actions except title_clearing.How do I rectify this?

Comment: I'd first be certain user.is? returns the role as a symbol, and isn't wired to return true no matter what. Is :title_clearing a custom action they can perform? Have you put this in place in your code? Something like `can? :title_clearing, Location`

Answer (score 1):

Maybe this because [Ability Precedence](https://github.com/ryanb/cancan/wiki/Ability-Precedence). With your definition in `ability.rb`, i think:

- The user has role `acquisitions` inherited abilities of user has role `titleclearing` and `admin` .
- And user has role `titleclearing` inherited abilities of user has role `admin`.

So, as you said, `"now everyone's being let through"`, because all user now have ability of `admin`. Try change the order of ability like this:

```
if user.is? :titleclearing
  can :title_clearing, :location
end
if user.is? :acquisitions
  cannot :title_clearing, :location 
end
if user.is? :admin
  can :all, :location 
end
```

and check if it works like you want.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
if user.is? :admin
  can :manage, :location
end
```

From [wiki](https://github.com/ryanb/cancan/wiki/Defining-Abilities)

> You can pass :manage to represent any action and :all to represent any object.